# Is there an easy way to restart a script if the user inputs invalid data

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically, I have a "raw_input" then an "if" statement and then many "elif" statements after it. If the user inputs invalid data I want the "else" to print a string, then restart the program so the user can try again. How can I do this?

Comment: Wrap your logic in a loop.

Comment: use `while True` loop to repeat your code. And `break` to leave this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a loop:

```
while True:
    # Code here
```

To exit the loop, use `break`, which will also quit the program.

```
while True:
    # Code here
    if running == False:    # The condition for breaking is up to you, if you're using one
        break
```